# Oracle - What is storage clause in altering a constraint statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL block to create a primary key constraint and in that SQL statement I found a clause

> storage initial

I couldn't understand what it do and what is the reason for putting it, can somebody tell me what that **storage initial** means when it comes to creating a constraint or index in oracle.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
....
....
STORAGE INITIAL
```

Comment: You can have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses009.htm#CJACEJGB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses009.htm), if the constraint requires an index, this clause allows defining how it should physically be stored (initial extent size...).